# No such file or directory FFMPEG with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run ffmpeg.exe with python.

```python
import subprocess
import os, shlex

cmd= os.chdir("ffmpeg.exe")
video = "test.mp4"
cmd = shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -i {video} test.avi')
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

But I'm getting an error.
`test.mp4` is in the same directory.

```
built with gcc 12.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.90_cf9beb1)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype 
--enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --disable-libmfx --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20221208
  libavutil      57. 43.100 / 57. 43.100
  libavcodec     59. 54.100 / 59. 54.100
  libavformat    59. 34.102 / 59. 34.102
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 52.100 /  8. 52.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
test.mp4: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this issue? I don't know what is the exact issue here. Thanks you

`Edit`: I solved the problem by changing the whole code structure. It's easier to work with directory.

```python
import subprocess

ffmpeg_path = r"ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"

ffmpeg_args = [
    "-i", "test.mp4",
    "test.avi"
]

subprocess.run([ffmpeg_path, *ffmpeg_args])
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with the full file path? i.e. `C:\...` I suspect that while `test.mp4` might be in your Python project/folder, `ffmpeg` might be looking there.

Comment: Where is `ffmpeg` located on your computer?

Comment: @AdrianDavidSmith It's located in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a debugging `print` statement to show the program's current working directory:

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: It's in the same directory. But it just give me an error.

Comment: How can that be? Please edit your post and show your **actual** code and your **actual, corresponding** output. You certainly must have errors if you are changing directory to `ffmpeg.exe`

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing the whole code. Thanks